# MediaRecorder Silence at Beginning of Recording (Delay?)

Tags: android, audio, delay, mediarecorder

My MediaRecorder is setup to record audio from the mic.  This works ... except that the first .65 seconds is completely dead air - its as if the first .65 second the record button was pressed but the mic had not turned on yet.

I need to determine if:

1. Something is wrong with my code
2. This is just a flaw in the way MediaRecorder works
3. 1 and 2 are true, but there is a work around!

Answer (score 6):

[RehersalAudioRecord](http://rehearsalassist.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rehearsalassist/android/trunk/src/urbanstew/RehearsalAssistant/RehearsalAudioRecorder.java?view=markup) contains some very well written code for recording in uncompressed WAV format.  Using this, recordings do not have the dead air at the beginning.  This class leverages AudioRecord, which is a lower level approach to using MediaRecorder.   Using this code as an example made the integration and transition from what I had super straightforward.

This answer got me there ... it took me a while to discover this so I post this self-answer in case it expedites someone's code spelunking.

[This answer is where I got my solution from ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437888/improve-android-audio-recording-quality/1615136#1615136)

////////////////////////////

But the class only provider a raw audio.we could not encode the audio file to arm or mp3 etc.