# Android Audio Recording

Tags: android

I need to record audio using AudioRecord class for a specific time. Let's say for 1 second. And then process the audio, and when the processing is done, record again for 1 second and keep repeating this until I close the program. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150592/need-a-simple-example-for-audio-recording

Comment: That link tells you how to record, which is simple. I'm looking for a way to time the recording. How would you record sometime for 3 seconds and then do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void recordandprocess()
{        

AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

        recorder.startRecording();

        //executes run() after 1000 msec
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
                      recorder.stop();
                      recorder.release(); 
                      // do your processing here
                      recordandprocess(); //recursive call to this function to start recording after processing is done
         } 
    }, 1000); 
        .
        .
        .
      return;
}
```

Call this function once in `onCreate()` and it will continue calling itself recursively until your activity is killed by the system.

If you want to stop recursion when you press back or home button, then check a boolean inside the function before executing all the code in it. Set the boolean to false in your `onPause()`.